# Issue with a constructor constraint in the generic type (XE4+)

Tags: delphi, generics, constructor, constraints

I have following generic class with some basic functionality and all it worked fine until one moment when I wanted to skip assigning the ConstructMethod for simple factories which just constructs the objects with .Create (without parameters or any specifics):

```
type
  EGenericFactory = class(Exception)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  end;

  EGenericFactoryNotRegistered = class(EGenericFactory);
  EGenericFactoryAlreadyRegistered = class(EGenericFactory);

  TGenericFactoryConstructor<C: constructor; R: class> = reference to function(AClass: C; AParams: array of const): R;

  TGenericFactory<T; C: constructor; R: class> = class
  protected
    FType2Class: TDictionary<T, C>;
    FConstructMethod: TGenericFactoryConstructor<C, R>;
    procedure SetConstructMethod(const Value: TGenericFactoryConstructor<C, R>);
  public
    constructor Create(AConstructor: TGenericFactoryConstructor<C, R> = nil); reintroduce; overload; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure RegisterClass(AType: T; AClass: C);
    function ClassForType(AType: T): C;
    function TypeForClass(AClass: TClass): T;
    function SupportsClass(AClass: TClass): Boolean;
    function Construct(AType: T; AParams: array of const): R;
    property ConstructMethod: TGenericFactoryConstructor<C, R> read FConstructMethod write SetConstructMethod;
  end;
```

And then I wanted to write the default constructor like:

```
function TGenericFactory<T, C, R>.Construct(AType: T; AParams: array of const): R;
var
  Cls: C;
begin
  Cls := ClassForType(AType);
  if not Assigned(FConstructMethod) then
    with TRttiContext.Create do
      Exit((GetType(Cls) as TRttiInstanceType).MetaclassType.Create);

  Result := FConstructMethod(ClassForType(AType), AParams);
end;
```

But... I cannot do anything like TypeInfo() or TRtiiContext.GetType() with result of ClassForType() function! The I tried other way which also fails:

```
function TGenericFactory<T, C, R>.Construct(AType: T; AParams: array of const): R;
var
  Cls: TValue;
begin
  if not Assigned(FConstructMethod) then
    begin
      Cls := TValue.FromVariant(ClassForType(AType));
      Exit(R((TRttiContext.Create.GetType(Cls.TypeInfo) as TRttiInstanceType).MetaclassType.Create));
    end;

  Result := FConstructMethod(ClassForType(AType), AParams);
end;
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? For now I just do the "copy paste" for the ConstructMethod assignment like:

```
F := TViewFactory.Create;
F.ConstructMethod :=
  function(AClass: TConfigViewClass; AParams: array of const): TConfigView
  begin
    if AClass = nil then
      Result := nil
    else
      Result := AClass.Create;
  end;
```

Comment: The problem here is that you need to explicitly refer to the actual class in order for your factory to create them. In which case there is no need (in delphi) to have the factory in the first place. Just use virtual constructors and be done with it.

Comment: You are porting Java code/concepts to Delphi. Java needs reflection here because it does not have virtual constructors, Delphi does not need this overhead.

Comment: Its actually not porting. I just wanted to avoid defining the contruct method each time. And as well i do not want to cast all the time from TClass.

Comment: And this factory saves from boiler plate for each.factory i need. I do not accept factory with result of TObject to do a cast after that..

Comment: Because with my current generic factory i construct and use it with any class and any virtual constructor with or without params.

Comment: The only problem is that when i use it with simple classes which are from TObject... i have to define that obvious construct method.. and i wanted to write it generic way but found thats not possible... so i asked maybe someone knows how to get the typeinfo from the ClassForType function result. Thats the source problem..

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot instruct compiler to understand the result of ClassForType function as "class of off" (class ref) and not as "class" (instance), but I found the way how to at least call the default constructor:

```
function TGenericFactory<T, C, R>.Construct(AType: T; AParams: array of const): R;
var
  ClsRaw: C;
  Cls: TClass;
begin
  if not Assigned(FConstructMethod) then
    begin
      ClsRaw := ClassForType(AType);
      Move(ClsRaw, Cls, SizeOf(C));
      Exit(R(Cls.Create));
    end;

  Result := FConstructMethod(ClassForType(AType), AParams);
end;
```

All the magic is that we just save the result of ClassForType to local variable and then copy memory to the variable of type TClass. Then we can normally call the Create!

Answer (score 0):

The factory pattern (like many other patterns in the GoF book) is a workaround for a missing feature in a language (in this case the lack of virtual constructors in Java).

The way this is normally done in Delphi is this:

1. Create an ancestor class with a virtual constructor (can have arguments, or not).
2. Derive descendants that override this constructor.
3. Create a `class of TAncestor` `TMetaclass`.
4. Create instances of the descendants using the Metaclass.

Done.

An example:

```
type 
  TParent = class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;  //virtual-> system resolves the actual type at runtime
  end;

  TParentClass = class of TParent; //Meta class

  TChildA = class(TParent)
  public
    constructor Create; override; //Don't forget to call inherited in the body.      
  end;

  TChildB ....

  implementation

  var
    Input: TArray<TParentClass>;
    Output: TArray<TParent>;

  procedure CreateLotsOfObjects(const input: TArray<TParentClass>): TArray<TParent>;
  var
    X: TParentClass;
    i: integer;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(input));
    i:= 0;
    for X in input do begin
      //because the constructor is virtual it will select the right one.
      //no need for a factory pattern or reflection.
      Result[i]:= X.Create; 
      Inc(i); 
    end;
  end;  

  procedure Test;
  begin
    SetLength(input,200);
    for i:= 0 to 199 do begin
      if Odd(i) then Input[i]:= TChildA else Input[i]:= TChildB;
    end; 
    Output:= CreateLotsOfObjects(input); //Creates 100 A's and 100 B's
  end;
```

Comment: Yes. There your factory is with exact constant metaclass type! But mine can accept any and i will not duplicate any code as you will. Once you get TOnetherBaseClass = class of TOtherBase - you will copy paste your code for this metaclass as well.

Comment: You are showing me the something like Factory implemented for only one certain TParentClass, but not a generic factory as I have...
Once you pass the exact class you get dependency. In my case I only know the base class but reference them by a certain enumeration type. And each certain class registers in the factory to map a value to the class. And then you even do not know anything about other classes, you only depend on factory (which is only dependent on the base metaclass).

i hope you get the idea...

Comment: So the is no dependencies on the certain classes. They are just included to the project or excluded and that's all dependencies you have with my case. So do you know how I can get the TypeInfo() or GetType() for the ClassForType(AType: T): C result? That will be really helpful Johan.

Comment: For the reference you can check the Head First Design Patterns - about Factory Pattern. And there is no dependency for the class you construct with Factory.